# 'sm' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, stdvector

What is wrong in below reference usage and what is the correct usage. I want to assign a reference to smaller size vector.

```
vector<int> R = {3,4,6,3,6,2,3};
vector<int> P = {5,9,8};

        if (P.size()>=R.size())
            vector<int>& sm = R;
        else
            vector<int>& sm= P;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in this part. But you cannot use `sm` later, as its scope will be the `if` or `else` part only.

You should use something like this:

```
vector<int>& sm = (P.size()>=R.size()) ? R : P;
```

Comment: Or declare it with R and P and then initialize it in the if-else

Comment: @Shirkam That won't work, as it is a reference. Reference must be initialized and cannot be redirected to another object

Comment: Oh, I missed that &. Thank you for your anotation.